# If pseudocode level questions are on topic, do they need to provide an attempt at a solution?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I recently ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64449346/1456253), which asks, in generic terms, how to implement a BFS related algorithm with particular constraints. Most importantly, it does not have any language tagged, nor does it seem to expect or provide code in a particular language. Unfortunately, the question is stated as a requirements statement rather than as a question. Because of this, I flagged it for closure, but now I'm having doubts.

Question-lacking aside though, it does seem like a clearly phrased set of requirements (blatantly homework, but thats not exactly relevant). Certainly, several people seemed perfectly capable of intuiting the fact that OP wanted a pseudocode implementation and wrote good answers.

Imagine a rephrasing of this question that was more specific about its question, yet remained in pseudocode territory. Would that be on topic for SO? I've searched all over on meta for guidance and found some related, but not quite helpful signposts:

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281646/1456253) is an exact match for what I'm wondering but has no resolution, only hinting that some questions may be better for Computer Science.

That delineation is better explored in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199424/840685). One of the answers states that questions that "do not refer to a concrete programming language" are likely to belong on CS.SE. Ok so maybe its better for CS.SE?

Finally [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339776/1456253) quoting [guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/840685) on the over meta indicates that algorithms in pseudocode "straddle the border". Great.

And it turns out that there is a [language-agnostic] tag. So maybe the content of the question, asking for help implementing pseudocode, is on topic.

But maybe thats not good enough. If this question were asked with the inclusion of the java tag, it would likely be closed for a different reason, that it was lacking an MCVE. Should the fact that it's just looking for a pseudocode answer protect it from that requirement? That OP needs to provide an attempt even in such a circumstance is given as a comment on the [first signpost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281646/1456253), but that hardly seems like consensus.

TLDR:
If generic pseudocode questions are on-topic for SO, do they need to provide an attempt at a solution?

Comment: AFAIK even "normal" questions do *not* require code. What they need is a clear problem statement, and code often just happens to be the most appropriate way to define that.

Comment: I do not think "an attempt at a solution" means code. (Why is your TL;DR at the end. If people reach the end, they read your post, no? :-)

Comment: The pseudocode aspect seems like a red herring to me. Either we should answer questions that show no evidence of the author to solve it themselves, or we shouldn't. Whether they use a specific programming language to present their question or instead use pseudocode, seems completely irrelevant.

Comment: See also closely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319526/question-put-on-hold-because-no-code-was-posted

Comment: This is quite related and worth a read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332201/1360803

Comment: Great, those are both very helpful, especially the NP vs non-NP distinction drawn between CS.SE and SO.